# LabVIEW: missing block diagram

Tags: labview

I have a two broken VIs with front panels that open fine, but I can't edit or run them, or open theis block diagrams.

One of these was made as a replacement for the first when it started to have this problem. I need to at least find out how to avoid this problem in future, so I don't lose work on bigger VIs.

I'm not sure if it makes any difference, but I very recently upgraded to LabVIEW 2013.

Thank you in advance.

This is the error I get when I try to run them:

"
VI has a bad connection to or cannot find a subVI or external routine.

This VI has a bad connection to or cannot find a subVI or external routine but 
it has no block diagram to show or fix the error. You must find or correct the 
subVI or external routine. Check for more information in the Explain dialog box 
in Get Info.
"

Before reverting to a previous version (using dropbox) I got a different error with one of them:

"
LabVIEW: Generic error.

An error occurred loading VI 'sweep harmonics first test.vi', LabVIEW load 
error code 6: Could not load the block diagram.
"

Comment: If you have no version of the VI itself, then you are lost. Please start using a source code control system. Dropbox is not an SCC.

Comment: You could try getting in touch with National Instruments tech support and sending them the problem VI(s).

Comment: There is an option called "Separate compiled code from source file" in the VI Properties (category General) – perhaps this one is chosen for the affected VIs, and the external source code cannot be found/loaded?

Answer (score 1):

One situation how this happened.

Sometime LabVIEW crashes, and it restart. After restart, LabVIEW will ask you to recover the autosaved code.

I personally always discard those autosaved code. If you do choose to recover  autosaved code, there is a chance the recovered code is corrupted. Once you save corrupted code to disk, you are probably going to lose the ability to open/save the block diagram ever again.

Having a version control system is usually a way to avoid minimize the damage when LabVIEW crashes. At worst, you loose maybe an hour worth of work.

Comment: Sounds quite likely, though I would hope LabVIEW is better designed than that, but I doubt it is. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't open Block Diagram of your VI, first check the suggestion by @Rodrigo - it is most likely just a "compiled" VI, which has Block Diagram removed.

If you think there is Block Diagram inside and it is just corruped - you may contact NI support. And if you want to look deeper by yourself, extract the VI to XML using [pyLabview](https://github.com/mefistotelis/pylabview), and look into the XML - there you can modify every single part of the VI. For example, you may start removing parts until it starts working.

I wouldn't go into manual VI editing unless you have at least a dozen of affected files though. For a single file, it will be faster to re-create it in LabVIEW instead of trying to understand the internals. If many files are affected - may be worth finding the issue in one, as other files probably have the same glitch, so you can make a script which extracts, modifies and re-creates VIs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, I believe what happens is that you are trying to run the VI's created as "DATA" for an executable, instead of the actual source VI's.

When you build an executable LabVIEW creates a copy of all the Top Level VI's dependencies into the support (DATA) folder which should be in the same directory as your executable.

Try opening the VI's that are marked as not having a block diagram and navigate to File>>VI Properties to check the path from which the VI is being loaded. If it's not the original VI, you can just replace it.